# Can we describe a relativistic quantum field theory in a "particles with position" framework _if_ we constain it somehow?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, quantum-interpretations

**EDIT:** I'm rewriting this with a different mathematical formalism that I think may be more appropriate and hopefully this will be clearer.

Yes, another conceptual question regarding quantum theory.

It is well-known that *relativistic* quantum field theory does not admit a direct interpretation in terms of particles with position, i.e. there is no "position operator" for such "particles", unlike in the case of non-relativistic quantum mechanics, as a consequence of a variety of no-go results.

Now some say this is because "it's about fields, and not particles" and phrases like "there are no particles; only fields" - however I find this response unsatisfactory. While maybe it works, I feel that it is just more intuitive given how that the theory is actually discussed and used in practice, if we have a picture that can be understood straightforwardly as being in terms of *particles*. Moreover, many lines of experiment just make sense to think of in terms of particles, e.g. we can measure the size of electrons, and we can see them hit screens as little dots. Although, maybe in the end it just is/will have to be otherwise, but I don't wanna put that shoe down until it's absolutely necessary.

Perhaps the strongest counter to this kind of thinking, I think, is that it seems the problem is actually *not* the "field" part, but the "relativistic" part. Non-relativistic QM with variable particle number can be cast as a QFT, rather straightforwardly, and I remember someone suggesting that this might even be a better way to introduce multiparticle QM. In other words, quantum mechanics suggests a sort of duality between fields and particles; and I don't see why that shouldn't carry over to the relativistic case as well, even if we may have to modify some of our "particle" notions a bit.

Qualitatively, I have heard that we can roughly consider a relativistic particle as being locatable down to at least some distance on the order of its *Compton wavelength*, i.e.

$$\lambda_C := \frac{\hbar}{mc}$$

. For an electron, with $m \approx 9.1 \times 10^{-4}\ \mathrm{yg}$, we get a $\lambda_C$ of about $0.4\ \mathrm{pm}$, or about 400 times smaller than a typical atom. So the non-relativistic quantum picture for atoms makes sense to a point - though interestingly, perhaps it fails "earlier" than one might feel! Indeed, this $\lambda_C$ is still about 400 times larger than an atomic nucleus! From that viewpoint, electrons really just refuse to wanna be pinned down!

My question, though, is if we can make this intuitive idea rigorous by making some kind of construction of the free-field RQFT that parallels the free-field NRQM-as-QFT. In particular, we can partially construct an NRQM-as-QFT as follows. Assume a vacuum ket, $|0\rangle$, exists. Then declare that there are a pair of *creation* and *destruction* operator *fields*, respectively $\hat{a}^\dagger$ and $\hat{a}$, which have the semantics "$\hat{a}^\dagger(X)$ creates a particle positioned exactly at point $X$ when applied against a state", and so logically should have

$$\langle 0| \hat{a}(X_2) \hat{a}^{\dagger}(X_1) |0\rangle = \delta(X_2 - X_1)$$

(which is the amplitude density to measure the particle created at $X_1$ as being located at $X_2$) so we can build up a state with imperfect localization, i.e. a non-trivial positional wave function $\psi_x$, via

$$|\text{world contains 1 particle with p.w.f. $\psi_x$}\rangle := \iiint_{X \in \mathbb{R}^3} \psi_x(X) \hat{a}^{\dagger}(X) |0\rangle\ dV$$

Then, my question is this. I have also heard places where it is described that in RQFT the action of the creation/destruction operators is "nonlocal". To my ear, that sounds like we should then just rescind

$$\langle 0| \hat{a}(X_2) \hat{a}^{\dagger}(X_1) |0\rangle = \delta(X_2 - X_1)$$

in favor of something like, say,

$$\lim_{|X_2 - X_1| \rightarrow \infty} \langle 0| \hat{a}(X_2) \hat{a}^{\dagger}(X_1) |0\rangle = 0$$

. Obviously this is not enough now to specify the shape of the two operators anymore, but the question is, is this loose enough to permit a fully relativistic (causality-respecting) quantum field theory in position space? Note that now $X$ is no longer an exact location; the measurement amplitude may now be nonzero even at a slightly different $X + \mathbf{ε}$, so this *seems* like it should not run afoul of the relativistic constraints, no?

Or does relativity really require even more from this that then prevents *any* useful assignment of a positional wave function with these semantics? If so, what exactly prohibits it?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Given any rapidly decaying position-space wavefunction $\Psi(x)$ you have a free QFT state $(2 \pi)^{-3} \int d^3 p \int d^3 x \Psi(x) e^{-i p x} a_{p}^{\dagger} \left| 0 \right>$, which is a proper state in the Fock space. Similarly, in QM you have $\left| \Psi \right>$ which is a proper state. Neither QFT nor QM allows you to localize the wavefunction to a single point. So you totally can describe relativistic particles with a free QFT. Are you asking about interacting QFT maybe?

Comment: @Prof. Legolasov: This seems to run counter to what I've been hearing regarding the Reeh-Schlieder theorem and the likes which seem to suggest not only can you not localize the particle to a point, but it cannot be localized smaller than its Compton wavelength, i.e. it cannot be localized _arbitrarily far_ which is the case in NRQ[M/FT]. So there must be some constraint on $\Psi(x)$ to reflect that fact, no?

Comment: Or is it just that $\Psi(x)$ cannot end up identically zero at finite distance from some point, but otherwise something like, say, an arbitrarily sharp Gaussian is okay?

Comment: You must mean that the states $\Psi(x)$ and $\Phi(x)$ wouldn't have a pointwise inner product anymore, which is why there isn't a position operator (try computing the inner product of two such states, you'll get a propagator that has the factor of $e^{-m |x_1 - x_2|}$). But the states still exist, and are commonly used by particle physicists as descriptions of particles in position space. It just turns out to not have the properties you expect it to have from nonrelativistic QM.

Comment: Bottom line is: the thing is what it is. You can call it a particle with a funny localization anomaly, or a field, or whatever else you want. As long as the math isn't changed (and the math behind free QFT is pretty much written in stone), it doesn't matter how you interpret it I think